# mmap file between unrelated processes

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

How does mmap() work between unrelated processes?

If I mmap a file on disk in one process does a process that comes along a short bit later and opens the file benefit from the mmap?

I see there are some ways to share between parent and child process,  I'm referring to processes which communicate with each other but are not parent/child.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two independent processes can use mmap(2) to share access to the kernel disk block cache holding the file data:

1) Process A opens a file, makes the file the desired size and creates an mmap(2) window into the file.

2) Process B opens the same file and creates an mmap(2) window into the same file.

3)  Now, the same kernel block cache data exist simultaneously in both processes.  Either process can modify the data and that data is instantaneously available in the other process.

This is the issue the MAP_SHARED flag is intended to provide.

Comment: ok thanks.    i couldn't tell by the docs if the 2nd process had to be forked off the first.

Comment: If process A map the file, but process B just read the file, what happed. Does two process share all the change even no `sync` is called?

Answer (score 0):

mmap creates a new mapping in your virtual address space.

what kind of benefit are you talking about , explain more.

```
process -1 mmap - a.txt
process -2 did not do mmap then it cannot access a.txt unless he opens a.txt using open/FILE and gets a file pointer.
```

Comment: if the OS has mapped a.txt to some pages in memory that process 1 can get to,   is there a way for process 2 to access those pages without having to re-mmap a.txt?

Comment: I cant think of a way, unless you have some sphisticated translation of one virtual address to another.